# toString method for a linkedList

Tags: java, junit, linked-list, tostring

I am getting strange output for my toString in my linkedList class.

I cannot use any methods, only String concat. So limited in how to approach this.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
if (head == null) {
return "";
}
String result = "";
Node curr = head;

while (curr.next != null) {
curr = curr.next;
result += curr.data + ", ";
}
return result;
}
```

I wrote a JUnit test that:

```
assetsEquals(
"8,6,7,5,3,0,9, " + "9,0,3,5,7,6,8", dataTest.noOrderList().toString());
```

and that noOrderList().toString() comes from:

```
public static noOrderList<Integer> noOrderList() {
return makeListInNoOrder(new Integer[]{ 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9, 9, 0, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8});
```

When I run the test I get:

```
expected:<... 3, 0, 9, 9, 0, 3[]> but was: <... 3, 0, 9, 9, 0, 3[, ]>
```

Was is the cause of this , in the [, ] how do I eliminate that comma?

Thank you

Comment: How does the list "8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9, 9, 0, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8" return a toString() of "3, 0, 9, 9, 0, 3"?

Comment: @Steve Smith: I suppose the output is just shortened for better readability? But s/he should not test with a symmetric list, because that unit test might hide accidentally creating the list in reverse order.

Comment: @yre , are you actually getting "[, ]" at the end of your list, or just a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always append the `", "` string to the result.

- So, for the first element, you append `"9, "`.
- For the second, it's `"0, "`
- and so on...
- Finally, you add `"3, "` for the last.

Instead, you should append the `", "` only if the next element is not `null`.

E.g.:

```
while (curr.next != null) {
curr = curr.next;
    result += curr.data;
    if (curr.next != null)
        result += ", ";
}
```

to save some comparisons, you should emit the `", "` before the element, and emit the first element before the loop:

```
//don't print head, since that seems to be empty in your implementation.
//also make sure head does not reference `null` by accident...
if (curr.next == null)
    return result;
curr = curr.next;

//1st element after `head`
result += curr.data;

while (curr.next != null) {
    curr = curr.next;
    result += ", " + curr.data;
}
```

I also noticed you never put the `head` element into the result. Is it empty, or is that a mistake?

Comment: Small note: The second variant is not that better than the first, since the string operation is a lot more expensive than a trivial check for `null`. But I think it's a better style, and in the future you might write loops for which the condition is more expensive than the actual body.

Comment: Thank you!
I tried this and am getting some other results from other test:
expected:<1, 3, 2[]> but was:<1, 3, 2[2]>

Comment: The second varient has this effect:
expected:<1, []3, 2> but was:<1, [1,]3, 2>

The first variant passes all JUnits

Comment: The second variant prints the `head.data`, too. Your variant (and the first) don't. Try adding a `curr = curr.next;`. I'll adapt the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. As I said in my small note, you might think about putting some data into the `head` element. I think that's better, but on the other hand I am old enough to care about a few wasted bytes on a machine with 16GB of unused RAM ;) & Thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

your override behaviour has this cycle

```java
while (curr.next != null) {
  curr = curr.next;
  result += curr.data + ", ";
}
```

when you get to the end of it you always add a comma no matter if there is another `curr.next`

if you can substring just remove it just after the cycle, if not you gotta check if `curr.next != null` one more time before adding the comma or start appending the first string out of the cycle and inside start the concatenation with the comma

Answer (score 0):

In your While Loop, we get to the last iteration where curr.next != null, and we still append a ", " to it.

You can check if curr.next.next == before appending the comma.